# Flutter - Screen does not refresh properly after re-selecting a dropdown menu

Tags: flutter

After selecting a project for the first time, the data is displayed correctly. When selected a second time, the displayed data overlaps.

```
 child: GenericDropdownForm<Project>(
                labelText: '',
                items: projectList,
                displayItem: (Project item) => item.name ?? '',
                onChanged: (value) {
                  setState(() {
                    projectIdWatcher = value!.id!;
                    yearWatcher = value.startDate!.year;
                  });
                },
              ),
```

This class is used to display a single cell in a DataCell DataTable widget. If it was a stateless widget then everything worked fine. But now I need to add data editing using POST, PUT, and DELETE methods. so I changed the widget to stateful and started using the initState method. and everything broke.

```
class AssignmentRatioField extends ConsumerStatefulWidget {
  const AssignmentRatioFieldStateles({
    Key? key,
    required this.allocation,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final EmployeeAllocation? allocation;

  @override
  ConsumerState<ConsumerStatefulWidget> createState() =>
      _AssignmentRatioFieldStatelesState();
}

class _AssignmentRatioFieldStatelesState
    extends ConsumerState<AssignmentRatioFieldStateles> {
  final EmployeeAllocationsService service = EmployeeAllocationsService();
  TextEditingController ratioController = TextEditingController();
  EmployeeAllocation? allocation;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    allocation = widget.allocation;
    ratioController.text = widget.allocation!.assignmentRatio.toString();
  }

  Color getColor(double value) {
    if (value == 100) {
      return Colors.green;
    } else if (value == 0) {
      return Colors.white;
    } else {
      return const Color.fromARGB(255, 255, 230, 0);
    }
  }

  TextStyle getStyle(double value) {
    return value == 100
        ? const TextStyle(color: Colors.white)
        : const TextStyle(color: Colors.black);
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      color: getColor(widget.allocation!.assignmentRatio as double),
      width: 70,
      height: double.infinity,
      child: TextField(
        textAlignVertical: TextAlignVertical.center,
        decoration: InputDecoration(
          labelStyle: getStyle(widget.allocation!.assignmentRatio as double),
          labelText: widget.allocation!.assignmentRatio.toString(),
        ),
        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
        style: getStyle(widget.allocation!.assignmentRatio as double),
        controller: ratioController,
        //onSubmitted: handleFieldSubmitted,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

`labelText` is to be removed. Now I use this to check if the data is delivered correctly after reselecting the project. Yes, the data is correct. However, they are not well assigned to `EmployeeAllocation? allocation;` and to `TextEditingController ratioController`

I was replacing the widget with stateless. Then the display after rebuilding the table works fine. I tried to provide data to the TextField of the widget via `widget.Allocations` and then everything works fine. but then I won't be able to edit the data several times in one session. the error occurs when I assign incoming data to a variable

```
 @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    allocation = widget.allocation;
    ratioController.text = widget.allocation!.assignmentRatio.toString();
  }
```

I've run out of ideas, any and all help is appreciated.